# TypeDescriptionProvider / HyperDescriptor implementation

Tags: c#, typedescriptor, typedescriptionprovider

I am currently populating my WPF grid using a data collection that implements `ITypedList`, with the contained entities implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.  All the properties are determined at runtime.

I'm wanting to implement [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) to help speed up performance, but the example on that page more refers to known types rather than runtime properties.

I would think that I'd need to implement a custom `GetProperties()` method or similar to tell the HyperTypeDescriptor what properties it needs to look at, but am not sure where that should be set.  I figure it's not difficult, but I'm obviously missing something.

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HyperDescriptor` implementation is indeed specific for compile-time properties, as it uses `ILGenerator` etc and caches the generated code. If you are using `ICustomDescriptor` you are *already* in a very different performance profile - for example, if your custom `PropertyDescriptor`s work against a dictionary or hash-table as a property-bag they may *already* be significantly faster than raw reflection.

It *may* be possible to further optimise it, but I'd need to know more about the specific implementation. But it would be non-trivial work, so first satisfy yourself that this member-access is actually a bottleneck, and that you couldn't do something simple like paging or "virtual mode" first.

(clarification: I'm the author of HyperDescriptor, so I know this area well)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was hoping you'd see this question!  I'll run some more profiling on my app first, and perhaps post another question about runtime property performance improvements should the need arise (I'll link from this).